# Centos binding server configuration with glue record

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind, nameserver

I have trouble with dns server at CentOS. I have domain cloudauth.me, I have bought it from godaddy.com.

I added glue record to this domain . I configured nameservers with ns1.cloudauth.me and ns2.cloudauth.me . And IP address of this subdomains is 199.175.53.128 which I configured at godaddy. 199.175.53.128 is ip of my VPS.

Now I want to configure dns server at CentOS.

My configuration is this `/etc/named.conf`

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;199.175.53.128; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; };
    recursion yes;
allow-recursion {127.0.0.1; 199.175.53.128;};

    query-source address * port 53;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;  

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

zone "cloudauth.me" {
type master;
file "/var/named/cloudauth.me.hosts";
 };

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

And domain zone file is this . /var/named/cloudauth.me.hosts

```
$ttl 38400

@                 IN SOA          ns1.cloudauth.me. ns2.cloudauth.me. (
100     ; serial
1H      ; refresh
1M      ; retry
1W      ; expiry
1D)     ; minimum

cloudauth.me.      86400   IN      A       199.175.53.128

cloudauth.me.      86400   IN      NS      ns1.cloudauth.me.

cloudauth.me.      86400   IN      NS      ns2.cloudauth.me.

ns1  86400   IN      A       199.175.53.128

ns2  86400   IN      A       199.175.53.128

www      86400   IN      A       199.175.53.128
```

The problem is domain cloudauth.me not working . I have checked many nslookup servers . my domain cannot resolved . What is wrong in my configuration?

Comment: As an aside, having "two" nameservers that are hosted from the same BIND instance is somewhat missing the point.

Comment: Unless you're expecting to receive email at ns2@cloudauth.me, I don't think your SOA is correct.

Comment: [dns.squish.net just now](http://dns.squish.net/traverses/d76220bd96f85cc8a526a6829ababa4a/detail) found your glue records ok, but gives an error of "The server refused our query".

Comment: Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: I have found problem. tank you

Answer (score 1):

I have found issue . issue is at this line

```
allow-query     { localhost; };
```

For remote access to binding server , this line must be fallowing

```
allow-query     { any; };
```

This replacement solved this problem